# Как создать новый контакт со старым RAW_CONTACT_ID?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin

Имеется контакт на устройстве, после его удаления и восстановления, ему присваивается новый `RAW_CONTACT_ID`. Каким образом можно присвоить ему старый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Невозможно.

По сути `RAW_CONTACT_ID` представляет собой первичный ключ в SQLite таблице контактов (зарезервированное имя `_ID`), соответственно, первичные ключи генерируются СУБД SQLite, обычно в режиме `autoincrement`. Фактически это означает, что данный первичный ключ не дается на редакцию.

Можно конечно попытаться получить root на девайсе, тем самым получить права на запись в таблицу контактов, затем скопировать таблицу контактов в другую, при этом озаботиться тем, чтобы в новой таблице был другой первичный ключ, потом перебить `RAW_CONTACT_ID` в старое значение (предварительно озаботившись, тем чтобы не было дублей старого значения), потом обратно скопировать копию на старое место, наложить новый первичный ключ - в общем все сложно - и главное надо ли?